# What happen to a Transaction if a HTTP POST fail during the response?

Tags: api, rest, http, post, exchange-server

I'm trying to communicate with cryptocurrencies exchanges thought **HTTP API**.
When I make a buy/sell order I would like to **handle** IO exceptions during the HTTP response and be sure to **don't duplicate the order**.

Some exchanges allow to use **Client Order ID**, so if an exceptions occurs, I can just check if the order **exists** with my own generated ID => So try again if the order don't exists.

But for exchanges which don't have this feature, I can't **check if the order exists** because I don't receive any results (Just a connection error).

So there is any rule in the HTTP world which says if a **POST response** is not correctly send back to the user => **Don't make the transaction** ?
(So in this case I can just try again and be sure to **don't duplicate** order)

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Refer this: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.2

If Post response times out, or you get a IO exception it is hard to trace it the execution failed or was successfully done on client you were calling.
Since POST are not idempotent (multiple calls is not equal to single call) but a GET call is. I would suggest to do a GET for data (created, check if cryptocurrency exchange executed) and based on result can do another POST call.